# How to sustain hover over child element?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar where I'd like for there to be a dropdown with some additional information and a few extra links, but that is also nicely aligned with the label (hence why I'd like to keep the info element a child, rather than a separate element). I can't seem to puzzle out how to keep the hover visible while you mouse over to the other links without separating the elements. Is there any way to accomplish this with pure CSS?

The HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">rules</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="glossary navlink">
        <a href="">glossary</a>

        <div class="dd-glossary">
          <div class="dd-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae ornare metus, vel scelerisque justo. Quisque et justo vel massa imperdiet cursus.</p>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  color: #efeeeb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navlink {
  display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efeeeb;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1) 0ms;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.glossary {
  position: relative;
}

.dd-glossary {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  z-index: -10;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dd-glossary:hover,
.glossary:hover .dd-glossary {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.dd-content {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narabas/nf8069ua/5/), thank you!

Comment: If you'd like further help with a CSS mega menu, you can check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the block styling rule to the `a` on `hover`, however, the height of your link does not span the whole height of the navbar. Try adding the `hover` rule to the `li` element instead.

That alone would suffice if the `li` was filling the whole height, which it isn't. I added a red background just to make it obvious and you can see there is a 1px space at the bottom messing the behavior. (Ignore the black line on top, it's from the window frame that was caught in the screenshot)

[image]

To fix that, I removed the padding from the parent `ul` and added `inline-block` to the `li`s.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  color: #efeeeb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navlink {
  display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efeeeb;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1) 0ms;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.glossary {
  position: relative;
}

.dd-glossary {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  z-index: -10;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dd-glossary:hover,
.sustain-hover:hover .dd-glossary {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.dd-content {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">rules</a></li>
    <li class="sustain-hover">
      <div class="glossary navlink">
        <a href="">glossary</a>

        <div class="dd-glossary">
          <div class="dd-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae ornare metus, vel scelerisque justo. Quisque et justo vel massa imperdiet cursus.</p>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  color: #efeeeb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navlink {
  display: inline;
  position: relative; /* Added position: relative to .navlink */
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efeeeb;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1) 0ms;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.glossary:hover .dd-glossary {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.dd-glossary {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  z-index: 1; /* Updated z-index to bring the dropdown above other elements */
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dd-content {
  margin-top: 0; /* Adjusted margin-top to remove space */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">rules</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="glossary navlink">
        <a href="">glossary</a>

        <div class="dd-glossary">
          <div class="dd-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae ornare metus, vel scelerisque justo. Quisque et justo vel massa imperdiet cursus.</p>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Key changes:

Added position: relative; to the .navlink class to serve as a reference for the absolute positioning of the dropdown.

Adjusted the top property of .dd-glossary to position the dropdown below the parent element.

Removed the negative z-index from .dd-glossary and set it to a positive value to ensure it appears above other elements.

Now the dropdown will stay visible while hovering over the links inside it, and you won't need JavaScript for this effect.